# Replace values in select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have simple select:

```
select id, user_value
from some_table
```

Where `user_value` is some number. When `user_value` will be 0, I need to replace it to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `case` expression:

```
select id,
       (case when user_value = 0 then 1 else user_value end) as user_value
from some_table;
```

If you want to actually change the value in the table, then just use `update` with filtering:

```
update some_table
    set user_value = 1
    where user_value = 0;
```